# Is it possible to bridge ssh through a 4G connection?

Tags: ssh, 4g

My case is the following: I will install some prototypes connected together with wifi (one device is the AP) in a distant site. I'd like to be able to remotely connect to my network for avoiding to travel.
As there will be 4G networks available there, I was wondering if a simple solution could be to have a smartphone connected to my wifi network, and use it to forward ssh client requests through 4G connection.

I have no idea if it's possible, how/depending on network operators, if there are standards and software (preferably android) for doing so.
Sorry it this question remains a bit vague, but any pointers would be appreciated.

There are also some 4G boxs that provide internet as wifi AP. I could change my network to connect to it, but I have no idea if I can reliabily get an address to this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN server might be an option. Like DD-WRT on a router, or your own dedicated VPN server.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Sorry also for my poor understanding.